# UPDATE record serialized - php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I have this problem, I have to update a record of a table that has the values of a serialized column. the call to the function works and passes the data correctly. I can enter the record, but I can not update. This is my code:

```
       public function update($user_id, $array_check)
{ 

        $arrayB = array();
        $array_check = unserialize($array_check);

        foreach ($array_check $key => $value) {
            if($value["id"] == $array_check){
                $idRow = $value["id"];

                if($value["value"] == "0"){
                    $valueRow = "1";
                }else{
                    $valueRow = "0";
                }
            }else{
                $idRow = $value["id"];
                $valueRow = $value["value"];
            }

            $row = array("id" => $idRow, "value" => $valueRow);
            $arrayB[] = $row;
        }

        $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE data_docs SET docs_selected = :docs_selected WHERE user_id = :user_id');
        $row = $stmt->execute(array(':user_id' => $user_id, ':docs_selected' => serialize($arrayB) ) );

        return $arrayB;
```

}

Comment: This is **far** too broad for SO's simple QA format; please read [how to ask an On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: We can not help you here with such vague and overly broad questions. Please go read [ask] first of all. Then go look into _image maps_ to figure out how to make portions of an image clickable. Combine with an AJAX request to send data pertaining to that click to the server, and insert it into your database there. If you are still unfamiliar with any of the keywords/techniques mentioned, then please start with some beginner’s tutorials on those.

Comment: post edit... please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

edit.

Replace this:

```
           $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE data_docs SET docs_selected = :docs_selected WHERE user_id = :user_id);
```

with:

```
           $deseralized = serialize($arrayB);
           $stmt = $this->_db->prepare('UPDATE data_docs SET docs_selected = '$deseralized ' WHERE user_id = '$user_id');
```